# Algorithm - matching student examination centers

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem of grouping the students to the nearest examination center. Here are the conditions/constraints:

1. There are X students and Y examination centers. Each center will hold a different number of students.
2. The maximum capacity of the total of examination centers can be greater than the number of students, but not smaller.
3. A student can have the smallest distance to more than 1 examination center.
4. The examination will hold at the same time for all examination centers.

For example, there are 11500 students and 15 examination centers. 5 centers (1 to 5) will hold 1500 students, 3 for 600 (6 to 8) and the other 7 (9 to 15) will hold 350 students.

I have developed the followings:

1. A database table with the student's location (register address) to each of the examination centers. Something like below

   ```
   Student ID  Dist-Ex1  Dist-Ex2 ... Dist-Ex14  Dist-Ex15
   1            10         70            20         50
   2            25         43            5          105
   ...
   11499        35         12             35         55
   11500        5          23              5         5
   ```
2. I can add a column of storing the nearest examination center to each of the student, and create a table like below:

   ```
   Ex centers           Nearest for no. of students
   1                     2000
   2                      500
   ...
   14                     150
   15                     500
   ```

But I don't know how to further proceed. I believe it is some kind of algorithm problem. I would be grateful if anyone would give me some idea.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This seems to be an instance of the Generalized Assignment Problem, which is NP-hard. Wikipedia has a nice explanation as well as a greedy algorithm that is not guaranteed to be optimal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem  The agent/task formulation corresponds to your problem if the "agents" are locations and "tasks" are students. The cost is the distance from location to student, and the profit is 1 for each student.

Comment: Maybe a max-flow algorithm could fit here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood you are looking for an **optimal solution** - (all students are assigned to their closest examination center). For this, we will reduce the problem to a **[max-flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem)**

Reduce the problem to a bipartite<sup>1</sup> graph `G=(V,E)` such that `V = {students} U {examination centers} U {S,T}` (all students, all examination centers, and two extra vertices S and T).

`E = CLOSESTS U {S} X {examination centers} U {students} X {T}` (S is connected to all centers, all students are connected to T, and CLOSESTS  - that we will now discuss).

Where `CLOSESTS  = { (exam,stud) | exam is the closest examination center to the student sutd}`

We also need a weight function `f:E->N` such that:

```
f(u,v) = capcity if u=S, v=examination center
f(u,v) = 1 if u is examination center and v is student
f(u,v) = 1 if u is student and v is T
```

The resulting graph should look something like this sample:

[image]
Now, run a max flow algorithm, like [edmonds-karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds-Karp_algorithm). If the max flow "enters" T is #num_studets, there is an optimal solution and it is denoted by the flow network achieved by the algorithm<sup>2</sup>. The max-flow algorithm will find how much flow to put in each edge, which is equivalent to how to assign a student to a center, without breaking the capacity limit.

**Proof:**

- If there is max flow of #students, all edges (student,T) are used,
  and all student has an incoming flow, and thus is assigned. Also, each examination center has at most `capcity` students assigned, and the
  solution is valid.
- If the max flow is smaller then #students, then there is a
  student that did not get a flow from an examination center, and is
  thus not assigned, and there is no optimal solution.

---

(1) Not exactly a bipartite graph because we added S and T, without it - it was.

(2)According to [Integral Flow Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Integral_flow_theorem), and since all weights are integers - there is an integral solution.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your help. I will have a look on the max flow as well as genetic algorithms

Comment: @kwytse: You are welcome. Note that genetic algorithm (GA) are heuristic - and do not find optimal solution. If you really want to find the optimal solution, and assign each student to its closest center - max flow is the way to go. Also see the edit - I added a photo that supposed to demonstrate how the graph will look like.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look on Genetic Algorithms here.

Take population of students and their assignments
your fitness function could give the greater value for the students with less overlap.

I've implemented Student/Scheduling problem while being in the university this way, it worked pretty good.

So I believe Genetic Algorithms is a way to go here

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

(I know this was asked 2 years ago, but maybe it will help someone)

It can be solved optimal with the hungarian algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) creating a bipartite graph as following:

- The left nodes represent the **students**
- The right nodes represent the **seats** of the 15 centers
- Insert an **edge** from each student to each seat with weight = Distance to Center
- Compute then a minimum weight matching

Problem: Your matrix has size 11500².

Solution: It is possible to model the problem without 'expanding' the  centers to their seats using the following algorithm (I will not go into detail):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem